# Handling float and double types with same generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

Say I have:

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    T[][] values;
    ...
}
```

I want to add a `+` operator that would handle int, long, float and double or any other type that the `+` operator for T is implemented.

For example (this does not work but conveys what I want to do):

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    T[][] values;
    ...
    public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T> A, Matrix<T> B)
    {
        values = ...;
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; ++col)
            {
                values[row][col] = A.values[row][col] + B.values[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would want a way to limit T to only types that have the `+` operator defined to get a compile time error but failing that a runtime exception would do.
Also I would like to add implicit conversions then from `Matrix<float>` to `Matrix<double>` but these cannot be defined in the `Matrix<T>` class, anyway around this?
I know T4 templates could be used to generate a matrix for each type, but then the types need to be specified before hand and I would like this to work for any types the operator is defined for.

Comment: Unfortunately, like any other static function, you cannot call overloaded operators in a generic class. I'm afraid T4 is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an expression that will handle the + operation:

```
private static Func<T, T, T> Add = InitAdd();
private static Func<T, T, T> AddInit()
  {
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression left = Expression.Parameter(type, "left");
    ParameterExpression right = Expression.Parameter(type, "right");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Add(left, right), left, right).Compile();
  }
```

In your + operator you can call the static add function:

```
values[row][col] = Add(A.values[row][col], B.values[row][col]);
```

Look at http://linqlib.codeplex.com/ in the extensions under the LinqLib.Operators namespace. Those extensions do exactly what you are trying to do.